# How to disable/enable button when the iput field is empty or filled using state in react js?

Tags: reactjs

I am new in reactjs.

- I was trying to build create-react-app with normal backend server. First i was trying to load the data from backend api using fetch using object itemId which depends on [item]. Now i want to disable the 'Add to Stock' button through 'increaseQuantity(itemId)}' event handler  when the (<input value={input} onInput={e => { setInput(e.target.value); }} type="text" name='text' placeholder='Restock The Item' />)input field is empty. Enable the 'Add to Stock' button through  'increaseQuantity(itemId)}' when the (<input value={input} onInput={e => { setInput(e.target.value); }} type="text" name='text' placeholder='Restock The Item' />)input field is filled.Then I update the value in the state using setInput and POST request to backend in the 'increaseQuantity(itemId)}' event handler.

  ```
        import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
            import { Link, useParams } from 'react-router-dom';
            const ItemDetails = () => {
                const { itemId } = useParams();
                const [input, setInput] = useState('');
                const [item, setItem] = useState({});
                // const [agree, setAgree] = useState(false);

                useEffect(() => {
                    const url = `http://localhost:5000/item/${itemId}`;
                    fetch(url)
                        .then(res => res.json())
                        .then(data => setItem(data));

                }, [item]);

                const increaseQuantity = (id) => {
                    let quantity = item.quantity;
                    let num = parseInt(input);
                    quantity += num;
                    quantity = parseInt(quantity);
                    const updatedDetail = { quantity };
                    console.log(updatedDetail);
                    fetch(`http://localhost:5000/item/${itemId}`, {
                        method: 'PUT',
                        headers: {
                            'content-type': 'application/json',
                        },
                        body: JSON.stringify(updatedDetail),
                    })
                        .then(res => res.json())
                        .then(data => {
                            console.log(data);
                        })
                }


                return (
                    
                        About To Book{itemId}
                        
                            
                            {item.name}
                            price: {item.price}
                            Quantity: {item.quantity}

                             { setInput(e.target.value); }} type="text" name='text' placeholder='Restock The Item' />

                             increaseQuantity(itemId)} className='btn btn-primary ms-4'>Add to Stock

                        

                    
                );
            };

            export default ItemDetails;
  ```

Comment: your code seems incomplete input html tag is missing, extra closing brackets...

Comment: I edited the context..I tried but input field is not showing before button..Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

- ! should not be double. If ! is double before input , then button is not working in filled input field.
- this could do the job

  ```
  <button disabled={!input}>Add to stock</button>
  ```

Comment: if you can share your code in codesanbox i can help.